# Spring Boot Consuming WebService - How to have multiple xsd and wsdl on different packages with gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, gradle

I am following this guide:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/

The jaxb task looks like this:

```
task genJaxb {
  ext.sourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generated-sources/jaxb"
  ext.classesDir = "${buildDir}/classes/jaxb"
  ext.schema = "http://localhost:8080/ws/countries.wsdl"

  outputs.dir classesDir

  doLast() {
    project.ant {
      taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
          classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
      mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)
      mkdir(dir: classesDir)

        xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema,
            package: "com.example.consumingwebservice.wsdl") {
            arg(value: "-wsdl")
          produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
        }

        javac(destdir: classesDir, source: 1.8, target: 1.8, debug: true,
            debugLevel: "lines,vars,source",
            classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath) {
          src(path: sourcesDir)
          include(name: "**/*.java")
          include(name: "*.java")
          }

        copy(todir: classesDir) {
            fileset(dir: sourcesDir, erroronmissingdir: false) {
            exclude(name: "**/*.java")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's working great if there is only one wsdl or even multiple wsdl (with a few tweaks) on the same package.

I need to process some XSD and WSDL and place them on different packages, but compile in the same source.

Example:

- wsdl1.wsdl -> com.example.wsdl1
- wsdl2.wsdl -> com.example.wsdl2
- xsd_folder1/*.xsd -> com.example.xsd
- xsd_folder2/*.xsd -> com.example.other_xsd

Then compile in the same project.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: would be nice to show what "tweaks" you used to work with multiple wsdl

Answer (score 3):

i had the same issue. I kinda made it work, not like i wanted to, but it does the job. Maybe it is going to help you. Otherwise i am interested in this (clean) answer myself.

```
configurations {
    jaxb
}


task genJaxb {
    ext.sourcesDirWsdl = "${projectDir}/src/main/generated/wsdl"
    ext.classesDirWsdl = "${buildDir}/classes/jaxb/wsdl"
    ext.schemaDirWsdl = "${projectDir}/src/main/resources/wsdl"

    ext.sourcesDirXsd = "${projectDir}/src/main/generated/xsd"
    ext.classesDirXsd = "${buildDir}/classes/jaxb/xsd"
    ext.schemaDirXsd = "${projectDir}/src/main/resources/xsd"

    outputs.dir classesDirWsdl
    outputs.dir classesDirXsd

    doLast() {
        project.ant {
            taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
            mkdir(dir: sourcesDirWsdl)
            mkdir(dir: classesDirWsdl)
            mkdir(dir: sourcesDirXsd)
            mkdir(dir: classesDirXsd)

            xjc(destdir: sourcesDirWsdl) {
                schema(dir: schemaDirWsdl, includes: "*.wsdl")
                arg(value: "-wsdl")
                produces(dir: sourcesDirWsdl, includes: "**/*.java")
            }
            xjc(destdir: sourcesDirXsd) {
                schema(dir: schemaDirXsd, includes: "*.xsd")
                arg(value: "-wsdl")
                produces(dir: sourcesDirXsd, includes: "**/*.java")
            }

            javac(destdir: classesDirWsdl, source: 1.8, target: 1.8,
                    debug: true, debugLevel: "lines,vars,source",
                    includeantruntime: false,
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath) {
                src(path: sourcesDirWsdl)
                include(name: "**/*.java")
                include(name: "*.java")
            }
            javac(destdir: classesDirXsd, source: 1.8, target: 1.8,
                    debug: true, debugLevel: "lines,vars,source",
                    includeantruntime: false,
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath) {
                src(path: sourcesDirXsd)
                include(name: "**/*.java")
                include(name: "*.java")
            }

            copy(todir: classesDirWsdl) {
                fileset(dir: sourcesDirWsdl, erroronmissingdir: false) {
                    exclude(name: "**/*.java")
                }
            }
            copy(todir: classesDirXsd) {
                fileset(dir: sourcesDirXsd, erroronmissingdir: false) {
                    exclude(name: "**/*.java")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and you put in your `dependencies`

```
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services') {
    exclude(group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
}
implementation('org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core')

implementation('wsdl4j:wsdl4j:1.6.3')
jaxb("org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:2.3.2")
compile(files(genJaxb.classesDirWsdl, genJaxb.classesDirXsd).builtBy(genJaxb))
```

Edit: I had started with a `package: com.example.somepck` in the `xjc` method, but i got it always overriden, so i moved it to the directory. As i said, it is not that clean, but for me it did the job. Maybe you can use it and tweak it if necessary.
If you have some imporvement, please let me know.